# Graphql Codegen: Issues generating hooks with types

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

I am using `graphql codegen` programmatically.

```
import * as typescriptReactApolloPlugin from "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo";

const config: Types.GenerateOptions = {
  documents: [{ document: doc }],
  config: {},
  // returns the string output, rather than writing to a file
  filename: "index.ts",
  schema: undefined,
  schemaAst: schema,
  plugins: [
    {
      typescriptReactApollo: {},
    },
  ],
  pluginMap: {
    typescriptReactApollo: typescriptReactApolloPlugin,
  },
};
const result = await codegen(config);
```

This is my document (Query):

```
query myquery {
  Users {
    limit
  }
}
```

And this is the generated result:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import * as Apollo from '@apollo/client';
const defaultOptions = {} as const;

export const MyqueryDocument = gql`
    query myquery {
  Users {
    limit
  }
}
    `;

/**
 * __useMyqueryQuery__
 *
 * To run a query within a React component, call `useMyqueryQuery` and pass it any options that fit your needs.
 * When your component renders, `useMyqueryQuery` returns an object from Apollo Client that contains loading, error, and data properties
 * you can use to render your UI.
 *
 * @param baseOptions options that will be passed into the query, supported options are listed on: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#options;
 *
 * @example
 * const { data, loading, error } = useMyqueryQuery({
 *   variables: {
 *   },
 * });
 */
export function useMyqueryQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.QueryHookOptions<MyqueryQuery, MyqueryQueryVariables>) {
        const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
        return Apollo.useQuery<MyqueryQuery, MyqueryQueryVariables>(MyqueryDocument, options);
      }
export function useMyqueryLazyQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.LazyQueryHookOptions<MyqueryQuery, MyqueryQueryVariables>) {    
          const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
          return Apollo.useLazyQuery<MyqueryQuery, MyqueryQueryVariables>(MyqueryDocument, options);
        }
export type MyqueryQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useMyqueryQuery>;
export type MyqueryLazyQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useMyqueryLazyQuery>;
export type MyqueryQueryResult = Apollo.QueryResult<MyqueryQuery, MyqueryQueryVariables>;
```

## Problem

The problem is that some types are missing e.g. `MyqueryQuery`, `MyqueryQueryVariables`.

How to fix that?

## Update:

Adding the plugins `typescript` and `typescript-operations` will generate additional types. But the hooks are no longer generated.

I made a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-kilby-kuiu4g?file=/index.js) showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add two more plugins:

- [typescript](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/typescript/typescript)
- [typescript-operations](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/typescript/typescript-operations)

If you're going to https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/ and select `React Apollo Hooks` from the Live examples, than you see the needed plug-ins in the `codegen.yml`-file. If you remove `typescript` and `typescript-operation` there, similiar output as in your example is generated.

Note: for each plugin you want to use, add another *object* to the `plugins` attribute of the `config` object. This object only has one key (name of the plugin) and as value another (potentially empty) object with config options for that plugin.

Example:

```js
const config = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    {
      typescript: {}
    },
    {
      typescriptOperations: {},
    }, 
    {
      typescriptReactApollo: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have modified your codesandbox with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-noyce-d200dg?file=/index.js

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried adding the other two plugins but it didnt work. I will make a codesandbox showing the problem.

Comment: I created a codesandbox @ https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-kilby-kuiu4g?file=/index.js. Thx for your help!

Comment: I modified my answer, see my example on how to use the plugins array